# Of whom are the photo portraits in Larry's office?

Tags: the-larry-sanders-show

In [*The Larry Sanders Show*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103466/) you can see a bunch of portraits hanging in *Larry*'s office, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Office]

The third from the top is Johnny Carson, but **who are the other three?**

Comment: What importance to the plot does this bring?

Comment: @TylerShads - So much _background_ to the plot(s)

Comment: Do you mind putting in that background for the uninitiated.  Frankly this looks like blatant trivia without it.

Comment: @TylerShads - I don't know what's wrong with trivia. This is, after all, somewhere to asks questions about Movies & TV, trivial or not. For the "uninitiated", they were all important players in the talk show world. See user5651's answer.

Comment: Relevant part of the [FAQ](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  *Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.* is not allowed.   Therefore information like this needs to be justified because to someone who doesn't know what the topic is about, it comes across as a simple "who are these people in these seemingly random pictures in the background?"  So in order to improve the quality of your question, I simply recommend that you add that kind of information to the text by clicking the *edit* button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top photo is Steve Allen. The bottom photo is Merv Griffin. The second photo is fuzzier but I'm pretty sure it's Jack Paar.